# MySQLi Multiple Row Insert Very Slow

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, wamp, innodb

I have an InnoDB table in WAMP that contains about 40 million records with the following structure:

```
CREATE TABLE sales (
  sale_id int(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  sale_type_id int(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  sale_employee_id int(12) unsigned NOT NULL,
  sale_period tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  sale_minute tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  sale_second tinyint(3) unsigned NOT NULL,
  sale_amount decimal(5,2) unsigned NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (sale_id, sale_type_id),
  KEY (sale_employee_id, sale_type_id, sale_period, sale_amount, sale_minute)
)
```

I'm using MySQLi to INSERT approximately 3,000 new records at a time using an array and "implode", as follows, which takes between 1 and 2 minutes to complete:

```
$insertArray = array();
foreach($phpArray->sales as $sale) {
    $saleId = (int) $saleId;
    $saleType = (int) $saleType;
    $saleEmployeeId = (int) $saleEmployeeId;
    $salePeriod = (int) $salePeriod;
    $saleMinute = (int) $saleMinute;
    $saleSecond = (int) $saleSecond;
    $saleAmount = $saleAmount;

    $insertArray[] = "('$saleId', '$saleType', '$saleEmployeeId', '$salePeriod', '$saleMinute', '$saleSecond', '$saleAmount')";
}

$insertSql = "INSERT IGNORE INTO sales (sale_id, sale_type_id, sale_employee_id, sale_period, sale_minute, sale_second, sale_amount) VALUES ".implode(",",$insertArray);
$insertResult = $mysqli->query($insertSql);
```

Is there anything noticeably wrong with the way I'm going about this?

Will INSERT IGNORE be markedly slower than INSERT?
Could the fact that I have a composite PRIMARY KEY be an issue?
Do I need to use quotes around each variable name in the insert array, and if not, will removing them speed things up at all?

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: 25rec/s does not sound too bad, give you have such a large index. The [MySQL documentation lists a few things](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/insert-speed.html) you can do. But I guess ultimativly you should consider partition the data (maybe by year?).

Comment: do you have power to change table structure?

Comment: Numeric values should not be in quotes in the value list.  MySQL may be OK with it, but they are unnecessary.

Comment: I do have power to change the table structure. How would I go about partitioning the table?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. turn off autocommit and manually commit in one request solved my problem.

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
// loop through all the new records
foreach($newRecordsArray as $newRecord) {
... do your foreach loop per record here.....             
    $insertResult = $mysqli->query($insertSql);
}
//do one commit     
if (!$mysqli->commit()) {
    print("Transaction commit failed\n");
    exit();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Inserting that many rows using `insert` is always slow. `Insert ignore` just ignores duplicate errors by skipping those inserts rather than throwing the error and stopping the whole batch, so that's not what's making it slow: inserting that many rows is what's making it slow.

To insert that many rows quickly, use `load data infile` in the mysql console, if you can.

It might also be possible to use  `load data LOCAL infile` from a PHP application, depending on the permissions of the user it uses to connect to MySQL.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. Would there be an easy way for me to use the above foreach loop to create a file to use for "load data infile"? Would this method be expected to be a lot faster than my above process?

Comment: @JimRollins Once you have a delimited textfile for `load data` to read, it seems nearly instantaneous in comparison to doing a bunch of `insert` statements.

Answer (score 0):

`INSERT IGNORE` is faster then `INSERT`.
Instead of creating an array and imploding it you could directly concat the string. it should a bit more efficient.

Composite primary key cost a bit more then a typical `id` key when inserting a new row since it's based on the B-TREE approach in MySQL (or hash indexes)

Answer (score 0):

Try to change from:

`$insertResult = $mysqli->query($insertSql);`

to:

```
$mysqli->query("START TRANSACTION");
$insertResult = $mysqli->query($insertSql);
$mysqli->query("COMMIT");
```

That could surprise you a lot :-)

Answer (score 0):

Yep, when performing many queries autocommit is harmful, use approach below:

```
$mysqli->autocommit(FALSE);
$mysqli->begin_transaction(MYSQLI_TRANS_START_READ_WRITE);

// multiple inserts here

$mysqli->commit();
```

Btw, you can check autocommit state  by query:

```
$mysqli->query("SELECT @@autocommit")
```